# scipy.signal.fftconvolve - more details?

Tags: python, audio, scipy, convolution

Could someone please tell me what is the FFT size used by scipy.signal.fftconvolve, and if there is a flexibility to change it? From the syntax, I do not see any options for that.
And does it use the overlap-add technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that convolution in time domain is equivalent to multiplication in frequency domain. It doesn't use any windowing (and hence no overlap-add technique). The length of the fft is the length of your input, eventually with zero-padding for getting an optimal size for [FFTPACK](http://www.netlib.org/fftpack/) (composites of the prime factors 2, 3, and 5, also known as [Regular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number)).